# scrollTop() gives different values on pages of different sizes

Tags: jquery

I want to detect when I am 100px on a page from the top, but it seems that I am getting different values for pages of different heights where the vertical scrollbar height is different.

I am detecting like so:

```
$( window ).on( "scroll", function() {

        console.log($(document).scrollTop());

    });
```

However, when I scroll down from the very top about a 100px (and I know it's about a 100 because the header has a height of 100px), on three pages with different heights I get the following logged basically: `180` `350` `480`

Why does it not simply state `100` when that is how far it is from the top of the window to the top of the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Try changing to ````$(window).scrollTop()```` and see if it affects the results.

Comment: nope, i get the same thing.

Comment: And ````$(document.body).scrollTop()```` also gives the same result? It feels like it can be solved by changing the element you use ````.scrollTop()```` on, but hard to decipher without being able to debug the DOM. Can you remove HTML elements (via browser Inspector) and shorten down the page to get the same results on all?

Comment: no because I have different elements on each page. Regardless, the space I see from the top of the page to the top of the scrollbar is the same on 3 pages, yet the logged value is different.

Comment: That is what leads me to believe that the node you're using scrollTop on isn't actually the same size on all pages, even though it might appear so in the rendered version of the page. When using the above script, does it go evenly from 0 to 180/350/480 or does it increment in different steps on the three different pages? Since you should be able to see every single pixel increase like in http://output.jsbin.com/ibefal/9

Comment: It increments every 4 px in my script. Well I tried using window, document and body to detect scrollTop, of course they are not the same height on each page, but what does that have to do with the end result, the way i see it it should just say how much from top, regardless of page height no?